# SSL no longer working after Ubuntu 14.01.1 LTS upgrade

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I upgraded my server to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and now I can not seem to get my SSL certificate to work correctly.

After the upgrade I had received an error when attempting to start Apache:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 11 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mywebsite-ssl
```

Line 11 consists of:

```
Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

I had commented this line out and then Apache would start. I went to my SquirrelMail on the server and HTTPS:// loaded just fine, but when I go to my actual website with https:// I got an Internal Server Error.

I attempted to find the problem in error logs, but nothing was recorded.

**My question**: Do I need to have Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks MultiView in order for my SSL to load correctly and if so, what do I do about Apache not restarting correctly when this line is not commented out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Ubuntu update you updated the Apache version. Latest apache changed some old syntaxes such as `Allow for all` (although you can bring them back enabling some modules).

The Internal Error simply means that apache had a problem requesting that page. Given that you commented `Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks MultiViews`, I suspect it needs to follow a symlink in order to open your actual website.

The problem with your line is probably this warning:

> Warning
>   Mixing Options with a + or - with those without is not valid syntax, and is likely to cause  unexpected results.

-- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html

I suggest you to change the line to:

> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

Comment: Apache 2.4 has [significant configuration changes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) compared to 2.2.  Ryan, if you haven't done it yet, you should review your entire Apache configuration to make sure it's working as expected in 2.4.

Comment: Ángel thank you for that information. I made the change, but still giving me the same error.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Thank you for letting me know that. I was not aware of these changes, but I'm also not very server savvy

Comment: @Ángel I followed the URL you sent me and I replaced the Allow for all that was being used as you mentioned and the problem seems to have fixed. Thank you kindly for your help!